# Table Not Found When Using %sql

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Exception thrown as follows for the code below when executing the %sql statement:

> Exception - org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: businessReviews; line 1 pos 14

Code:

```
val business_DF = sqlCtx.read.json("/Users/tom/Documents/Spring 2016/Java/Project/YELP/yelp/DS - YELP/yelp_academic_dataset_business.json").select("business_id", "categories", "state", "city", "name", "longitude", "latitude")
import sqlContext.implicits._
business_DF.registerTempTable("businessReviews")

%sql
select * from businessReviews

ZEPPELIN_SPARK_USEHIVECONTEXT set to False in zeppelin-env.sh
export ZEPPELIN_SPARK_USEHIVECONTEXT = false # Use HiveContext instead of SQLContext if set true. true by default.
```

Comment: check this example https://github.com/alvinhenrick/apache-spark-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/yelp/example/AnalyzeJSONWithDataFrame.scala

Comment: I want to use %sql so I can see the graphical representation of queried output.  The example above doesn't use show graphical representation

Comment: check this: http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/hello-world-an-introduction-to-hadoop-hcatalog-hive-and-pig/#section_8

Comment: @Prateek Mane I am facing the same issue with zeppelin have you got any solution around tihis

Answer (score 1):

Adding in the beginning this row:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("yarn").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me*:

```
%pyspark 

business_DF = spark.read.json("/tmp/yelp_academic_dataset_business.json")
business_DF = business_DF.select("business_id", "categories", "state", "city", "name", "longitude", "latitude")
business_DF.registerTempTable("businessReviews")

%sql
select * from businessReviews
```

> [image: zeppelin screenshot]

However, I wouldn't bother with the temp table for the purpose you've described. You can just use `z.show(<dataframe>)`, e.g.:

```
%pyspark 

business_DF = spark.read.json("/tmp/yelp_academic_dataset_business.json")
business_DF = business_DF.select("business_id", "categories", "state", "city", "name", "longitude", "latitude")
z.show(business_DF)
```

> [image: Zeppelin screenshot 2]

*Using Spark 2.0.0, Python 3.5.2 and a snapshot build of Zeppelin (@04da56403b543e661dca4485f3c5a33ac53d0ede)